# Secure KeyVault using Virtual Network

Tags: azure, azure-keyvault, azure-virtual-network

I want to restrict access to azure keyvault using virtual Network. but when i configure it as below. and i expect to be able to manage secrets when i am on VPN(the selected Vnet). but it doesn't allow me.
[image]

[image]

Comment: Does it work publicly? (Just to rule out access policies). This works for everyone else so I guess the question is: are you certain you are on the allowed IP adress range?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you allow access only from specific VNETs (and Subnets) you are leveraging Service Endpoints (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-network-service-endpoints-overview).

This means that only VMs from the particular VNET/Subnet can access the service endpoints and thus the service. The corresponding FAQs state:

> By default, Azure service resources secured to virtual networks are
> not reachable from on-premises networks. If you want to allow traffic
> from on-premises, you must also allow public (typically, NAT) IP
> addresses from your on-premises or ExpressRoute. These IP addresses
> can be added through the IP firewall configuration for the Azure
> service resources.
> Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/virtual-networks-faq#can-an-on-premises-devices-ip-address-that-is-connected-through-azure-virtual-network-gateway-vpn-or-expressroute-gateway-access-azure-paas-service-over-vnet-service-endpoints

Unless you would like to completely disable public access and leverage Private Endpoints, you would need to add your on-premises public IP address to the firewall rules. Please note that you will then connect to the key vault through the public internet - your network traffic is not going through the VPN tunnel.

The only way to fully leverage private network traffic is to use Private Endpoints.

Comment: Thank you @holge for the explanation. it was so helpful.  i have managed to setup private endpoint and it's working fine. :)